# Is it possible to use safari within an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to use Safari in-app with full features? (especially adressbar + search + tabs)? 
If so, can I also access to the addressbar content + site title?
If not, is there any other "browser framework" which can be used completly in-app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIWebView and UIWebViewDelegate to write yourself a custom in-app browser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly access the Safari.app.

You can open a link into Safari but the user needs to leave your all for a while.

Also, you could create a Safari clone in your app. You need to create a UIWebView and it shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: I want to add some functionality to safari, so the user should stay within my app to browse the web - could I create a complete clone of Safari with UIWebView, or would it be limited?

Comment: All depends about which features precisely you want to clone.

Comment: It's not going to be like safari, the webview is worst, for example, javascript runs slower.

Comment: First of all, create a UIWebView and see what it can do. Then adapt it to your needs.